# How to add event listener to videojs when start to play a video?

Tags: javascript, video.js

How do I add event listener to videojs when the video is start to play? (this event should be called at the begging of the play)?

I searched on [Player Events docs](https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Eventsended), but I can't find any event that tell me "now the video is start play".

Comment: I'm not familiar with this player framework, but based on the demos it seems to me that it uses `<video>` tags, which have their own event for start, called `play`,  maybe you can subscribe to that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this videojs way.

```
play.on('play', () => { });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking [the docs for the `<video>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).

You will see many events are emitted. Most importantly,

> play - Playback has begun.

We can add an event listener to the element listening for this event:

```
document.querySelector('.video').addEventListener('play',  evt => { 
   // code you want to happen when the video plays
});
```

**Note**: `document.querySelector('.video')` is just a filler, select the element however you want to

I suggest this over @FlashThunder's solution because you can add multiple listeners and for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

right there on the docs you have the timeupdate event, you could set a flag to true when it starts.

Comment: event time this function is invoked. I have to use a global var to know if it starts. I looking if videojs have this option

Answer (score 0):

That's only a "skin" for HTML5 player, you can access the original HTML5 element by `.player()` function, and then use [those](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp):

```
var vid = myplayer.player();
vid.onplay = function() {
    alert("The video has started to play");
};
```

> **player()**
>
> Return the component's player